# jQuery animations still act as a queue, even when queue: false

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm currently making a small fade-in fade-out subnavigation menu. Everything is working fine except for the fact that when I mouseover, the sub-nav menu fades in first, then animates down. I need this to happen simultaneously, so I went ahead and disabled the queue but for some reason it still fades and then animates in a sequence :C. The funny thing is: when I mouse-out, it moves and fades simultaneously! Very confusing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.subNavMenu").fadeTo(0,0);
    $("ul.navMenu").hover(
        function() {
            $("ul.subNavMenu").animate({opacity: 1, marginTop: "20px"}, {duration: 1000, queue:false});
        },
        function() {
            $("ul.subNavMenu").animate({opacity: 0, marginTop: "0px"}, {duration: 1000, queue:false});
        }
    );
});
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Hmvd3/2/

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm confused. It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/nickaknudson/Hmvd3/. What browser are you on?

Comment: That's odd! It works there for me, too. I'm on the latest version of chrome.

Comment: I performed more tests on mine. It seems that the fade in starts, and then shortly after it will move it down while still fading in. In essence it seems that the animations are in fact overlapping, but each animation is offset from the other by some milliseconds.

Comment: It must have something to do with my CSS:
http://jsfiddle.net/Hmvd3/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can try stop().

```
$("ul.navMenu").hover(
        function() {
            $("ul.subNavMenu").stop().animate({opacity: 1, marginTop: "20px"}, {duration: 1000, queue:false});
        },
        function() {
            $("ul.subNavMenu").stop().animate({opacity: 0, marginTop: "0px"}, {duration: 1000, queue:false});
        }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The default easing is *swing*. Setting `easing: 'linear'` should solve your problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/nickaknudson/Hmvd3/

**RESOURCES**

- http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with your css?